# Converting phenol to phenetole

Tags: organic-chemistry

*Disclaimer: high school question*

I was hoping to make phenol do a nucleophilic attack on $\ce{C2H5Cl}$. But then, I noted that the $\ce{O}$ atom in phenol is NOT as nucleophilic as the regular $\ce{R-OH}$ (since it delocalises with the benzene ring). So, I am afraid phenol's $\ce{O}$ atom might not be a good enough nucleophile to achieve the conversion by this method.

Is there any other method to achieve this conversion?

Comment: Actually it is a better nucleophile than standard -OH. Your idea of Phenol plus ethyl chloride under basic conditions is perfectly sound. I would suggest using ethyl iodide though as it is more reactive and ethyl chloride has a boiling pt of 12C making it difficult to keep in the reaction mixture.

Comment: @Waylander oh, I didn't have basic conditions. You're right, I missed the basic concepts. Closing as a duplicate. Thanks a lot for your help! :D